# I want write process Synchronization for .Net application

Tags: process, automationelement

I am automating my .net application using **AutomationElement** I want to write process synchronization for my framework. Is there any **WINAPI** .net API which can tell us whether process is busy or not.I am using Windows 7 OS and .Net 4.0 framework..

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API function.

> It waits until the specified process has finished processing its initial
>   input and is waiting for user input with no input pending, or until
>   the time-out interval has elapsed.